# Connect view pointer to view object ios x

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, macos

I'm reading the book IOS Programming The Big Nerd Ranch 4th edition.

In the book it says: The project’s template made one
additional connection: the view pointer of BNRQuizViewController is connected to the View objectthat represents the background of the application.

Here is the connection inspector from the book
[image: mac2]

However, in my connection inspector, the view does not have this kind of connection. How can I do this connection?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I connect a IBOutlet to a UIView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14576515/how-do-i-connect-a-iboutlet-to-a-uiview)

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xq-a7e_l_4I