# Prototype UITableViewCell with other objects (UITextField, UISwitch)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, tableview

I'm trying to make a `UITableView` that can support having different objects/elements inside it. Specifically, these elements are a `UITextField` and `UISwitch`.

**The first problem:**

The elements do not show up. They are placed in the prototype `cell`, which is then constructed inside the `class` I have set up. I have verified that the `cell` setup is working because I can change the words on each `cell`, but there are no elements within the `cell`.

Here is the code that constructs my cells right now:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int{
    return 1
}



public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: "EmailCell")
    return cell
}
```

**Second problem** (which might be solved along with the first):

I have no way of accessing the information in each `UITextField` or each `UISwitch`. How can I get this information from all cells that exist?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Is the style of the prototype cell set to `custom`?

Comment: You have to show the code that you are using to "construct the cells inside the class". Also, a screenshot of your Storyboard may be helpful.

Comment: It seems like you're trying to create a form. You can try out https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka

Comment: @vadian Yes it is set to custom

Comment: @TheMooCows237 can you also show your `EmailCell` implementation?

Comment: @naglerrr What exactly do you mean by that? `EmailCell` is currently just the reuse identifier for the prototype cell, and there is no code associated with it. (besides the declaration in the `cellForRowAt` method)

Comment: Ok, so that is your problem. You need a `UITableViewCell` subclass `EmailCell`. I just added an answer explaining how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong with your code.

For custom cells you need to implement a custom `UITableViewCell` subclass. Here is an example:

```
import UIKit    

class EmailCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var customTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var customSwitch: UISwitch!

}
```

After that, open your Storyboard and select the prototype cell. Change it's class to `EmailCell` in the Identity Inspector.

[image]

Also make sure to connect your ui elements to the `@IBOutlet`s created earlier. See [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14578106/4294969) if you need help with `@IBOutlet`.

[image]

In the next step, change your `tableView(_:, cellForRowAt:)` implementation like this:

```
public func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "EmailCell", for: indexPath) as! EmailCell

    // Configure your custom ui elements however you want
    cell.customTextField.text = "somestring"
    cell.customSwitch.isOn = true

    return cell
}
```

Comment: This works fantastically! Thank you so much. One thing, do you know how I would detect a change in the text field or switch within my _view controller_ class? (This is the class that contains tableView setup)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your cells have reuse identifiers and you're using

```
tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: -Your cell Id- , for: indexPath) as? -Your Cell Class-
```

in  your cell for row at index datasource method

next you can add targets to your cell text field / switch by doing this in your cell for row at index datasource method

```
cell.-your switch / text field-.addTarget(self, action: #selector(valueChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
```

and you should subclass a uitableview cell to add the property / iboutlets

```
class YourTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

  @IBOutlet weak var yourSwitch: UISwitch!

}
```

Comment: Okay, I added the dequeueReusableCell to inside the cellForRowAt method. However, I cannot call cell.[switch/ text field] because it doesn't recognize that there is a text field inside the prototype cell. I also cannot link the text field as an outlet because XCode gives me an error saying that I cannot link outlets to repeating content.